# Prevent showing result if data is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I run this SQL query, it should not show the result if `ShopID`, `company` is null

It returned null because `member_id` can not be found in the `Shop` table.

```
SELECT username, group_id, T.company, T.ShopID
FROM members AS M
LEFT JOIN Shop AS T ON T.member_id = M.member_id
WHERE M.member_id =15
```

How can that be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a RIGHT or INNER join instead of a LEFT join.

LEFT JOIN means return the left-hand side of the join even if there's no right-hand side.
RIGHT JOIN means return the right-hand side of the join even if there's no left-hand side. INNER JOIN means only return a record if both sides of the join have a record.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT username, group_id, T.company, T.ShopID
FROM members AS M
LEFT JOIN Shop AS T ON T.member_id = M.member_id
WHERE M.member_id =15 AND NOT (ShopID is null OR Company is null)
```